# JavaScript in a php generated button

Tags: php, javascript

The code below prints a button as shown. The buttons work in all browsers except IE. How can i add javascript on it?

```
print "<td>" ."<a href='advancedview.php?id=$uniqueid' STYLE='text-decoration: none'><input type='Button' value='More Details' style='width:100%;height:30%'> </a>". "</td>";
```

I tried ...`onClick='advancedview.php?id=$uniqueid'` but its not workin on ie. Thanks

Comment: i wonder how did it work in other browsers...!

Comment: Not working as in, nothing happens when you click the button?

Comment: could you please clarify what are you actually trying to do...?

Comment: When clicked nothing happens. @ Sudhir you know IE has issues with buttons.

Comment: onClick takes JAVASCRIPT not a URL

Comment: Why do you set the same URL in the `href` and in the `onclick` properties? `onclick` accepts javascript code, not URLs...

Comment: The problem is on IE only guys. I want users on IE to have the buttons instead of a URL

Comment: Don't use <a href> then ;)

Comment: "The problem is on IE only guys" - regardless, onClick takes JAVASCRIPT. Even if your stuff works on other browsers, THIS PART DOES NOT. The href of the <a> makes it work, but the onClick code still is WRONG, because it isn't (JS) code. (I SCREAM because that improves my arguments somehow)

Comment: Thanks  Mörre for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A buttons onclick event parses javascript, so if you'd like to change the location you set window.location

```
echo "<td><input type=\"Button\" onclick=\"window.location='advancedview.php?id=".$uniqueid."'\" value=\"More Details\" style=\"width:100%;height:30%\"></td>";
```

Comment: Thanks Craig. The code i posted works well with all other browsers except IE. I thought JS would enable it to open the linked page.

Comment: Great. Thanks Craig1231. That one is working in all browsers.